# notepad++ changing a URL

Tags: notepad++

I have an account on Newspapers.com. The syntax to manually download an image is using example id of 999:

https://www.newspapers.com/download/image/?type=jpg&id=999

But if you manually try to download an image without using their special software the broken URL it gives you is:

https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?

The second link doesn't work. It needs to be changed to the layout of the first one. How do I change the second line to include the information from the first line in Notepad++?

Sometimes the URL which needs changing has extra information at the end. For example:

https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?terms=randomletters 
or 
https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?terms=randomnumbers

How do I have the code remove everything after the /999 part?

Answer (score 0):

- Start notepad++
- Paste the links you want to fix
- Open the replacing dialogue via `Ctrl` + `H`
- Set `Find what` to `^(.*?)(\d+)(\D*)$`
- Set `replace with` to `https://www.newspapers.com/download/image/?type=jpg&id=\2`
- Enable search mode `regular expression`
- click `replace all`

Done. How this works:
The only identifier we have is the group of digits. Therefore, we grab the whole string with a regular expression and capture the digits in the second capturing group. We can then replace the whole string with the fixed one that we know is working, pasting in the digits where they're needed.

If you want to play around with this a bit, I highly recommend regex101.com.

Comment: Sometimes the URL which needs changing has extra information at the end. For example:

https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?terms=randomletters

or 

https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?terms=randomnumbers

How do I have the code remove everything after the /999 part?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `https://www.newspapers.com/\K(image)/(\d+)(/\?)\S*`
- Replace with: `download/$1$3type=jpg&id=$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
https://www.newspapers.com/ : literally
\K                          : forget all we have seen until this position
(image)                     : group 1, literally "image"
/                           : a slash
(\d+)                       : group 2, 1 or more digits (ie. the id)
(/\?)                       : group 3, a slash and a question mark
\S*                         : 0 or more non space character
```

**Replacement:**

```
download/       : literally "download/"
$1              : content of group 1, (ie. image)
$3              : content of group 3, "/?"
type=jpg&id=    : literally
$2              : content of group 2, (ie. the id)
```

**input:**

```
https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?
https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?terms=randomletters 
https://www.newspapers.com/image/999/?terms=123456
```

**Result:**

```
https://www.newspapers.com/download/image/?type=jpg&id=999
https://www.newspapers.com/download/image/?type=jpg&id=999 
https://www.newspapers.com/download/image/?type=jpg&id=999
```